# WebView callback from Javascript

Tags: webview, javafx, javafx-2

I tried to create a simple example of callback from Javascript to Java, based on the [last example in WebEngine's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) (*Calling back to Java from JavaScript*). But when I click the link in the WebView, the Java method is not called and the page disappears.

```
public class TestOnClick extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            final WebView webView = new WebView();
            final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

            Scene scene = new Scene(webView);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setWidth(1200);
            stage.setHeight(600);
            stage.show();

            String webPage = "<html>\n"
                    + "    <body>\n"
                    + "        <a href=\"\" onclick=\"app.onClick()\">Click here</a>\n"
                    + "    </body>\n"
                    + "</html>";

            System.out.println(webPage);

            webView.getEngine().loadContent(webPage);

            JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class JavaApp {

        public void onClick() {
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I don't see any exceptions being thrown in the WebView when monitoring the load worker with  `webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(...)`.

Comment: **Note for readers:** Starting from 2.2.5 the bridge class (`JavaApp` in this case) must be declared `public`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to access webview DOM model before it was created.

Wrap your `JavaApp` related code to the page load listener to achieve your goal:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State t, State t1) {
        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This apporach introduces a race condition if loaded page needs to access some application API at startup, because page JavaScript is executed before `RUNNING` -> `SUCCEEDED` transition happens.

Comment: to solve this classic problem of concurrent access you can use any standard approaches: e.g. wait in js till variable app is initialised.