# Calling a Java method using javascript from within a JPanel

Tags: java, jlabel

I have a Java application which displays results on a JPanel. The results are displayed using HTML by using a JLabel.

Now I want to let the user interact with the local application by allowing local methods to be called when the user clicks on a link in that HTML document.

Is this possible?

Comment: Using servlet you can achieve this.

Comment: `displays results on a JPanel` != `results are displayed using HTML`. You're doing one or the other, not both.

Comment: @RyanStewart The OP is saying that _is displayed_ ***using*** _HTML_, which is perfectly possible if he is writing html into a `JLabel`/`JEditorPane` and adding that to a `JPanel`.

Comment: The html is written in a JLabel

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question, then, it is possible, however you cannot use a JLabel, you need to insert a JavaFX component, and then you can set your class as a window variable on the DOM, and thus your methods can be called from JavaScript.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543458/97627) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541933/webview-callback-from-javascript). It looks like they are doing exactly what you want.