# Why can't I embed Ace Editor into WebView?

Tags: java, html, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I am attempting to make a simple editor in JavaFX 2.2. I downloaded `Ace Editor` repository and created a test page which works fine when double clicked.

However, it does not work when I try to embed it into the `WebView`.

**SSCCE**:

```
package web;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.web.WebViewBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditorTrial extends Application{
    WebView webView;
    WebEngine engine;
    StackPane stack;
    Scene scene;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primStage) throws Exception {
        stack = StackPaneBuilder
                .create()
                .alignment(Pos.CENTER)
                .build();

        webView = WebViewBuilder
                .create()
                .build();

        engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.load("/home/little/Downloads/AceEditor/ace-builds-master/MyTrial.html");
        stack.getChildren().add(webView);

        scene = SceneBuilder
                .create()
                .root(stack)
                .build();

        primStage.setScene(scene);
        primStage.sizeToScene();
        primStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch("web.EditorTrial");
    }
}
```

**Can someone please tell me what is wrong?**

Comment: *Note: Google opens properly*

Comment: Try adding the `FirebugLite` and check out the console if there are errors.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev and how do I add the tag you showed to the webview ?

Comment: Add it under the `<head>` anywhere: `<script src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'>`

Comment: It would be better to start a chat. Starting it from previous question

Answer (score -1):

It works for me when the absolute file path : 
try

```
File f = new File("/home/little/Downloads/AceEditor/ace-builds-master/MyTrial.html");
String StrURL = f.toURI().toURL().toString(); 
engine.load(StrURL);
```