# SceneBuilder does not show 3rd party controls

Tags: java, javafx

I have read [an answer about using the code highlighting component RichTextFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21500429/4136325).

I have set up the JAR file to be in my Java Build Path (.classpath), but I can't find a RichTextFX component in Scene Builder. I searched for `CodeArea` in the library filter.

Next I have added the `<CodeArea />` tag in the FXML file by myself. It has imported the `org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea` automatically, which tells me that my classpath settings are ok. But it still doesn't show up in Scene Builder.

I tried `File/Import`, `File/Include` and `File/Preferences` to get the JAR file included, but no luck.

How do I get 3rd party controls into Scene Builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a small gear icon besides the library filter. JAR files can be imported from there.

[image: Screenshot importing JAR file]